# How do I assign type as instance of a class using jsdoc?

Tags: jsdoc

I have `Example` class and a `something` function where the first argument is `example`, how do I document `something` so that the `example` argument is typed as an instance of `Example`?

```
class Example {}


function something (example) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class is discoverable by the function, as in, it's in the same file.

```js
/**
  * @param {Example} example
  */
function something (example) {

}
```

If jsdoc can't find it, then imports work like this:

```js
/**
  * @param {import('./example')} example
  */
function something (example) {

}
```

Or this depending on how `Example` is exported.

```js
/**
  * @param {import('./example')['Example']} example
  */
function something (example) {

}
```